# Testing user's pronunciation of Arabic against correct pronunciation

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, decomposition

I'd like to be able to compare two audio streams: one containing the correct pronunciation of Arabic text (from the Quran), and the other containing one from a user learning Arabic. Here is a sample of what Arabic sounds like in case it helps: https://youtu.be/ZYaZ6Odbx_Y

Questions I'd like to be able to answer:

1. Did the user pronounce everything correctly? Or close enough.
2. Which words did the user pronounce correctly? This will require splitting the audio streams into words.
3. Which letters did the user pronunce correctly? This will require further breaking down the word into letters, which I'd imagine should be similar to #2. Perhaps a little trickier to identify some letters, but I have the textual source to help and I might be able to do a large preprocessing of the data to learn the profile of each letter.
4. Going deeper into the intricate rules of Arabic. I have the domain expertise in Arabic that would help here, and it's also something I'd rather postpone solving to later.

While my general algorithm knowledge is strong, my knowledge of signal processing is fairly limited.

1. Do you have any suggestions of how to solve this problem? Do any existing libraries implement such analysis?
2. Where can I start to read up on this topic?
3. I hope this allowed here, but if not tell me and I'll remove: I'm looking to hire someone to build a prototype of this. If successful, I hope to develop this into a shippable Android app. I have a design doc if anyone is interested.

Comment: Interesting! I'm not an Arabic speaker (at all!) and this is fascinating: There's a unique correct pronounciation for texts! Does that apply only to the Quran, or also to other texts? Why I ask this: I wouldn't know which pronunciation I would consider "more" correct: [Boris Johnson](https://youtu.be/X1GHwp0fL7U) or [Scarlett Johannson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5I-Jh2HkK14) or [George Carlin](https://youtu.be/tbXj_kTv-0g) (or honestly, just speech models of these two persons) reading Genesis I, but both are native English speakers that definitely speak "high, standard English".

Comment: (and, do you *really* now the pronounciation of English before a ~70 year old Scotsman has insulted you after you've tried to explain your preference for more taste of peat in your drink?)

Comment: This only applies to the Quran. Because there's so much emphasis on getting hundreds of thousands to memorise it, way back over 1000 years ago they got rid of all dialects, reducing to one main dialect. There still remain minor differences, but the majority conform to one. Now there are seven styles of recitation, but *only* seven and these are localised to major regions. So the whole of the UK for example will mostly adopt one style. Obviously individual accents creep in, and that's OK (and part of the challenge here), but one should strive as much as possible to match the golden recitation.

Comment: This is *really* cool! Do you know whether there's some text-to-speech model that was trained to recite the Quran exactly like that? You could use the speech feature vectors used to generate the sound from that and train a Neural network to infer the same vectors from sound, and then compare feature vectors.

Comment: Also you reference the Bible, and I think an English translation. Once you translate it, you lose the reason for maintaining a standard recitation. Even the words differ between translations.

Comment: I'm not aware of such, and I somewhat doubt it. Although you have given me an idea I want to look into regarding that.

Comment: https://github.com/semarketir/quranjson/blob/master/source/tajweed/surah_1.json So I have found this, which is not a text to speech model, but it does codify the rules you need to apply to generate the sounds.

Comment: Nice, if you can somehow convert these rules into numbers (and if it's just how much you apply which rule for any word, i.e. most of these numbers would be 0 most of the time), you might have a chance of finding a mapping from sound to these numbers (such a mapping would be a neuronal network in its specific parametrrization), then let that same network loose on the learning speaker and compare its output to the reference

Comment: This is almost certainly not a "one guy and a computer" kind of effort -- it's a team of one or a few PhD's, and either a massive neural network that'll need tens of thousands of test vectors, or some really detailed rules-based speech recognition.

Comment: @TimWescott Do you think it's going to take more than one to build my step one above (to get a prototype going; I've been working with the idea of scaling up to three within a few months of things go well)? Would the test vectors come from the recordings of the correct recitation? Or also incorrect user recitation? I don't think a rules based approach would work. The rules are too many and some rather complicated.

Comment: Generally for training neural nets you need to have a whole bunch of known good examples, and a whole bunch of known bad examples. In your case, you will also need to make sure that both of the good and the bad examples are from a number of different speakers. Otherwise you may end up, for instance, training the neural net at any time someone with a bass voice is speaking everything is fine, and anytime someone who is a tenor speaks then the accent is wrong.

Comment: I can easily get various distinct good recitations, but I'll have to work on finding distinct bad recitations. I just came across a paper that seems to solve this problem, and they used a mixture of both. I contacted the author to see if I can get their data and/or code. This is the paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326010238_Using_Deep_Learning_for_Automatically_Determining_Correct_Application_of_Basic_Quranic_Recitation_Rules