# Splitting Arabic speech by letter

Tags: python, speech-processing

I have the audio stream below, which is a recording of Arabic. I am trying to split the stream into individual letters. I have manually marked the ideal locations with black lines in the image below. As you can see, there are definite feature changes at all these points, which gives me hope. Even the fourth one could potentially be further split into two about a third into that segment.

I have had partial success using Python's `pydub` library's `split_on_silence()` function. It's more geared towards finding word breaks, by looking for periods of silence. Given the partial success with this again gives me hope.

Any ideas on where I can go with this in an attempt to find these breaks using DSP techniques? It's as if I need to find the points where the frequency spectrum changes, but I have no idea how to do that.

[image]

For background, I am trying to solve this problem: [Testing user's pronunciation of Arabic against correct pronunciation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73342/testing-users-pronunciation-of-arabic-against-correct-pronunciation)

UPDATE: The second image below is of the filtered signal and STFTs. I'm still getting familiar with interpreting these plots, but I think it's showing each STFT vertically by shading based on the magnitude of each frequency for that STFT. The time axes roughly align (there's just a border around the first). I don't see the distinguishing features I had hoped for. I wonder whether it's the amplitudes I need to look at, as those visually appear to be changing?

[image]

UPDATE2: Attached plot with a 2nd degree moving average (using Hilbert transform).

[image]

UPDATE3: Attached plot with moving average (using my own method of averaging over 17 points) in orange, and STFTs of this moving average. This time I extended the plot to the full audio file, which is longer than the initial wavelength I posted right on top. More features are becoming apparent. Is it enough to detect these features?

[image]

Comment: Can you also do a STFT with a time block that is a fraction of your word size (maybe 1/5 as you would be trading time and frequency resolution)? Seeing that together with this may reveal other items of detection in the frequency domain that are clearer to distinguish.

Comment: I like that idea! I'm also thinking of different ways of searching for the correct boundaries, as this will be for training so can be offline (performance not as much of an issue). Then I have datasets of the letters and rules applied in each of these audio files, which I can use to learn what the spectrum of each looks like on average (I also have sources from different people saying the same things). This will have to wait till the end of the day, as I study mornings, but I'm excited to try this. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I added results from some STFT analysis. Can you take a look and let me know if you have any further ideas? I've never tried interpreting such data, so to me it doesn't appear to be revealing much.

Comment: I agree; I don’t see much either. You could do an envelope detector (absolute value with moving average) and then use features of that signal - perhaps two moving averages to determine a drop in the short term relative to the long term (reminds me of stock trading analysis techniques)

Comment: Added new plot with that added.

Comment: Sharing some thoughts that come to mind. What would make the stft plot look like this one? Why would it appear so relatively uniform when there are distinct features visible in the time domain? Also, perhaps an artefact of the plotting resolution, but why does it appear as though there are two distinct frequency bands in the time domain plots? The relationship between the two being different for each letter/segment of the data.

Comment: Added another couple plots (explained in the body of the question). Features are looking stronger, but are they apparent enough to detect?

Comment: We won’t be able to have an extended discussion here as it will soon be flagged, but hopefully what you’ve done may lead to a real answer